# Subquery returned more than 1 value. this is not permitted when the subquery follows = or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, subquery

I want to update on my 'MakinelerVeParcalar' table with this query ;

```
UPDATE MakinelerVeParcalar SET Durum = 'Montaj' WHERE ID = 161
```

And I got this error;

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trgSureUpdate, Line 31 [Batch Start Line 0]
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

My trgSureUpdate(Trigger)

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgSureUpdate]
ON [dbo].[MakinelerVeParcalar]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @count INT
    DECLARE @idinserted INT
    DECLARE @duruminserted VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @max INT
    DECLARE @iddeleted INT
    DECLARE @durumdeleted VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @datediff INT
    DECLARE @durumbilgisi varchar(50)
    DECLARE @sureinserted INT
    DECLARE @suredeleted INT
    DECLARE @diffdate INT

    SELECT @idinserted = ID from inserted  <-- Line 31
    SELECT @duruminserted = Durum from inserted
    SELECT @iddeleted = ID from deleted
    SELECT @durumdeleted = Durum from deleted

    SET @count = (SELECT count(*) FROM Sure WHERE ID = @idinserted and Asama = @duruminserted)
    SET @max = (SELECT max(SiraNo) FROM Sure WHERE ID = @idinserted)
    SET @durumbilgisi = (SELECT DurumBilgisi FROM DurumBilgisi WHERE ID = @idinserted)
    SET @sureinserted = (SELECT Sure FROM Sure WHERE ID = @idinserted and Asama = @duruminserted)
    SET @suredeleted = (SELECT Sure FROM Sure WHERE ID = @iddeleted and Asama = @durumdeleted)

    IF @duruminserted != @durumdeleted
    BEGIN


        IF @durumbilgisi != 'Bitti'
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Sure Set Cikis = GETDATE() WHERE Asama = @durumdeleted and ID = @idinserted and SiraNo = @max
            SET @diffdate = DATEDIFF (SECOND,(SELECT Giris FROM Sure WHERE ID = @idinserted and SiraNo = @max),(SELECT Cikis FROM Sure WHERE ID = @idinserted and SiraNo = @max))
            UPDATE Sure SET Sure = (@diffdate) WHERE ID = @idinserted and SiraNo = @max
        END
        INSERT INTO Sure (ID,Asama,Giris,Cikis,Sure,SiraNo) VALUES(@idinserted,@duruminserted,GETDATE(),NULL,0,(@max+1))
        UPDATE DurumBilgisi SET DurumBilgisi = 'Devam Ediyor' WHERE ID = @idinserted
    END
END
```

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are (virtual) tables.  You are not taking into account that they might have multiple rows so your trigger code is just bogus.

Comment: can u give me sample ?

Comment: The Microsoft documentation is filled with examples . . . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.  And there are zillions more examples on the web.

Comment: cannot solve :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confused on the line numbers. You have this marked as line 31, but it will NOT throw your error even if there are multiple rows on INSERTED:

```
SELECT @idinserted = ID from inserted
```

However, this WILL throw your error if the SELECT returns more than 1 row:

```
SET @durumbilgisi = (SELECT DurumBilgisi FROM DurumBilgisi WHERE ID = @idinserted)
```

There are differences between the `select @var = col from table` syntax and the `set @var = (select col from table)` syntax. You need to examine the `SET` queries.